# PHP send email PEAR fail

Tags: php, email, pear

[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

I'm trying to get this to work. According to the answer in the given link "it's working code so use it". Except it doesn't work for me.

In particular:

```
<?php

       require_once "Mail.php";

        $from = "<xxxxx.gmail.com>";
        $to = "<xxxxx.gmail.com>";
        $subject = "Hi!";
        $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

        $host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $port = "465";
        $username = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
        $password = "*****";

        $headers = array ('From' => $from,
          'To' => $to,
          'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
          array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));

        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
          echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
         } else {
          echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
         }

    ?>  <!-- end of php tag-->
```

Produces:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be
>   called statically in F:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 23
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   F:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail\smtp.php on line 365
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   F:\xampp\php\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 450
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   F:\xampp\php\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 467

While phpinfo() gives registered sockets:

> tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls

But most importantly, no email sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting correct email addresses in `$from` and `$to`

```
'PeterMorgan@gmail.com' instead of '<PeterMorgan.gmail.com>'
```

From PEAR Mail documentation:

```
include('Mail.php');

$recipients = 'joe@example.com';

$headers['From']    = 'richard@example.com';
$headers['To']      = 'joe@example.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';

$body = 'Test message';

$params = ... // set smtp values here
              // http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php

$mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: I've tried that. Doesn't seem to work. It waits about 25 seconds to load before showing the `strict` messages. It doesn't say the connection has failed or been refused... it just doesn't send.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. For GMail they say on their website:

> Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
>
> Port for SSL: 465
>
> If you're having trouble sending mail but you've confirmed that
> encryption is active for SMTP in your mail client, try to configure
> your SMTP server on a different port (465 or 587).

So I changed the port from 465 to 587, even though I am using SSL. I don't know why this works for me but it does.